# Cassandra row update check in a table

Tags: python, cassandra

Is there any way to check whether a row in a table has been modified or not in Cassandra.
I don't want to compare the date before and after updating row in table.
After Update operation I need to verify the query executed properly or not using python scripts. I am using Cassandra Driver for python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to verify that an update happened as planned, execute a SELECT against the updated row.